# Errors while obfuscating Coreutils Programs with Tigress

Tags: obfuscation

I'm currently working with the [**Tigress obfuscator**](https://tigress.wtf/index.html) to obfuscate Coreutils programs (version 9.3). As a source-to-source obfuscator, Tigress should ideally be able to handle this task. However, I'm facing challenges during the obfuscation process, and for illustrative purposes, I will use ***wc*** as the obfuscation target in this context.

The command I'm using to attempt the obfuscation is:

`tigress --Environment=x86_64:Linux:Gcc:4.6 -I ../lib/ --Transform=InitOpaque --InitOpaqueStructs=list --Functions=main --Transform=EncodeLiterals --Functions=main --out=wc-obf.c wc.c`

However, this command results in the following error:

`/usr/include/wchar.h[396:8-16] : syntax error Parsing error/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function '_start': (.text+0x20): undefined reference to 'main' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

I've experimented with different versions of *gcc* (specifically 4.8, 7, and 11) in an attempt to resolve the issue, but unfortunately, these efforts have been unsuccessful as the error persists across all gcc versions I've tried.

I'm seeking advice or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve the error. Any insights would be greatly apprecaited!